# the basemap of QuickMapService changed when exported from print composer layout?

Tags: qgis-3

I was trying to export the layout, which was supposed to be like this:

[image: ideal image exported]

However, the exported image became untidy and unclear because of many secondary information were added, such as those tiny road names or county names.

[image: unwanted image]

How do I print the image as it appears in print composer layout?

The basemap is Bing Map from plugin `QuickMapService’.